# Win 10 UAP ListView Conditional Separator

Tags: windows, listview, windows-10, win-universal-app

For a ListView I want to display a separator between Items. However, what makes it kinda difficult is that it should only be displayed when the date changes.

So i want all the items from 1.1.2015 listed. Before the items of 2.1.2015 start, there should be a separator (in this case just the text with the date).
Therefore I would need to access the last item somehow.

My idea would be to put a TextBox at the beginning of the `<LV.ItemTemplate><DataTemplate>`, bind the date and hook it's visibility up to a converter. But for that the converter needs to know what date came before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done very simply using an out of the box `ListView` with a grouped `CollectionViewSource` to which the `ListView` is bound.

A very simple overview of how to do this:

To your xaml page, add

```
<Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="itemsViewSource" IsSourceGrouped="true" />
</Page.Resources>
```

For the ListView you can then do

```
<ListView x:Name="friendsList" Width="200" Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource itemsViewSource}}">
    <ListView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock
                    Text="{Binding Key}"
                    FontSize="40" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ListView.GroupStyle>
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Ellipse Margin="8" Width="32" Height="32">
                    <Ellipse.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="UserHero" Stretch="Uniform" ImageSource="{Binding picture.small}"/>
                    </Ellipse.Fill>
                </Ellipse>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding first_name}" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding last_name}" Margin="8" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

This snippet binds the itemsSource of the `ListView` to the `itemsViewSource` `CollectionViewSource` defined above.  The `DataTemplate` contains exactly what you want: the divider to display between the groups of elements!  This can be bound to the key that the grouped data belongs to and a converter used to do whatever you want to do!

The `ListView` items are then displayed from the list object paired with the key in the source data.

Now this works, how do we get the data into the format our xaml wants it in to use this...

In the code behind, I am going to assume you have a `List` of objects you're wanting to display as I don't have any information from your original questions, such as `private List<Object> _objects`.  What we need to do is convert this into a `List<GroupedInfoList<Object>> _groupedObjects`.

We can do this using the wonderful `LINQ`.  To illustrate this I will show you a snippet from one of my projects using an real data object in my project (the details of the object are not important):

```
public async Task<List<GroupInfoList<object>>> GetFriendsGrouped()
{
    if(_friends == null)
    {
        _friends = await NetworkManager.GetFriends();
    }

    List<GroupInfoList<object>> friendsGrouped = new List<GroupInfoList<object>>();

    var query = from friend in _friends
                orderby ((Friend)friend).first_name
                group friend by ((Friend)friend).first_name[0] into g
                select new { GroupName = g.Key, Items = g };
    foreach (var g in query)
    {
        GroupInfoList<object> info = new GroupInfoList<object>();
        info.Key = g.GroupName;
        foreach (var friend in g.Items)
        {
            info.Add(friend);
        }
        friendsGrouped.Add(info);
    }
    return friendsGrouped;
}
```

This snippet is taking a list of `Friend` objects, and grouping them by their `string first_name` attributes.  You will obviously need to tweak this LINQ query to group the objects by date which is what you want!

Once you have your grouped objects, you need to bind it to your `ListView` in your code frontend:

```
if (_friendsGrouped != null)
{
    var cvs = (CollectionViewSource)Resources["itemsViewSource"];
                   cvs.Source = _friendsGrouped;
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

As mentioned by the OP, `GroupInfoList` doesn't exist as a standard class, I had defined it myself as follows

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace App.Models
{
    public class GroupInfoList<T> : List<object>
    {    
        public object Key { get; set; }
        public new IEnumerator<object> GetEnumerator()    
        {
            return (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<object>)base.GetEnumerator();    
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The GroupInfoList doesn't exists for me (universal app) but i just put in the LINQ and resharper changed the return type to IOrderedEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime,Person>>. Other than that, it works great. Thanks :)

Comment: My bad, that is a custom class I forgot to include.  Updated the answer to show what I had for it